# How to authenticate Laravel client app from Laravel server app using passport in Laravel 10?

Tags: api, single-sign-on, laravel-blade, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I'm new in using Laravel Passport, I'm trying to make an SSO App. I already have 2 Apps. A Laravel Server with Passport Installed and Laravel Client App.

All my users registration is done on the server side and are saved on server database while on client app, I don't have user table. What I'm trying to achieve is, I would like my Server App to be my user management. But I also want my Client app to share same users info and credentials from my server app. And once users are authenticated to server app, they will also be authenticated to client app. I have already achieved this using session but I don't think it's a safe way. So here's my client callback

```
public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        
        $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => '993fed57-cb86-4c26-a001-a485ccea5334',
            'client_secret' => 'UZUvZtPcrkOg4ICgeq5h87fH1hOFMYt7AujJPNBH',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/login/oauth/callback',
            // 'code_verifier' => $codeVerifier,
            'code' => $request->code,
        ]);

        //initialize user session
        $user_session = [];

        $response = $response->json();
        //insert access token to user session
        foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
           $user_session[$key] = $value;
        }

        //fetch user data from server
        $user = Http::withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $response['access_token'],
        ])->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user');

        $user = $user->json();

        //insert user info to user session
        foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
           $user_session[$key] = $value;
        }
       //insert session to token table
        $session = [
            'user_id' => $user['id'],
            'token_type' => $response['token_type'],
            'access_token' => $response['access_token'],
            'refresh_token' => $response['refresh_token'],
            'expires_in' => $response['expires_in'],
        ];

       OauthToken::create($session);

         //Put user session to session method
        foreach ($user_session as $key => $value) {
            // dd($value);
            $request->session()->put($key, $value);
        }
       
        

        // dd($request->session()->get('access_token'));

        if ($request->session()->get('access_token')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is instead of saving user's data to session, I want to use the Laravel's Auth::class to authenticate users on the client side.

Comment: How did you implement this? Were you using a custom IDP?